# Zsh returns 'bad pattern' when attempting to Flash esp32

Tags: terminal, embedded, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I recently switched over to zsh, and I ran into an issue while using my ESP32.

Before I began to build the project, every other command ran fine. However, when I attempt to run

**idf.py -p cu.usbserial-DN0316ED [-b 115200] flash**

I receive the following error: **zsh: bad pattern: [-b**

I have looked up this issue to see if anyone else has experienced something like this, and found some similar cases regarding Zsh plugins interfering with commands that contain () or []'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `[]` around the `-b 115200`.

You probably copied this command from a website which uses these brackets to imply that this part of the command is optional. As such you could drop `-b 115200` and the command should still work.

Here is the documentation for the usage of [`idf.py`](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#idf-py). The `idf.py flash` explains the `-b` flag.

Comment: Thank you soooo much, this has been a problem for a few days now. Thank you for providing the documentation as well.

Comment: - Side note - I am really passionate about Embedded Systems engineering (building IoT devices), would you be willing to recommend any documentation for my pursuit down the rabbit hole?

Comment: @KheperahRay Please accept my answer if it was sufficient to solve your problem. This can be done by clicking on the arrow beneath the voting buttons. Seeing as you are using the ESP32, my guess would be the [Espressif ESP32 docs](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/index.html). General programming courses are also a good recommendation (for whatever language you are using `C/C++/micropython/lua/javascript`)